# Adding a titled color bar and generally getting a colored scatter plot to look good

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter, colorbar

I'm creating a scatter plot that is colored according to a 2-d array, but having trouble getting the color bar set up correctly alongside it. What I have so far is:

```
self.fig1 = plt.figure('blahblahblah', (10.0,10.0)))
ax2=plt.subplot(111)
ax2.set_ylabel('blah')
ax2.set_xlabel('blah')
ax2.set_title....
...
...
cmap, norm = mpl.colors.from_levels_and_colors9[0.9, 0.975, 1.025, 1.1],['green', 'red', 'blue'])
ax2.scatter(firstarray,secondarray,c=colordefiningarray,marker="o",cmap=cmap,norm=norm, vmin=0.9,vmax=1.1)
cax=self.fig1.add_axes([0.95, 0.2, 0.02, 0.6]) #pulled these #s from another question, no idea what they mean
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, spacing='poportional')
cb.set_label('moreblah')
#saving fig
```

The color bar is showing up, except it doesn't have a title. Also, i feel as if there is a much easier way to this, but I can't seem to figure it out from other questions.

EDIT: I now know it's an issue with the saved image scaling. I don't know how to scale the image without scaling the figure. Help?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: It would be best if you didn't abbreviate (i.e. remove) your code ... creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps people know what exactly your issue is.

Comment: The parts left out were just titling of axes - not relevant to the issue I was experiencing. I should have left the savefig command in, because that's where the issue ended up being, but I don't think that's the specific place you had in mind.

Comment: Indeed, good that you didn't omit anything critical, but the thing is, only you know what you omitted, we here have no way of knowing if what was omitted is critical or not. It also makes the code un-runnable, and for debugging people like to try your code for themselves to find any errors. And often the process of creating a mcve helps you find the problem yourself, which is always best.